# What is the simplest way to implement transparent objects in sharpdx?

Tags: graphics, transparency, sharpdx

I am currently trying to implement semi-transparent polygons in sharpdx.

At the moment I am using GraphicsDevice and BasicEffect to draw my objects.

```
// Setup the vertices
game.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(myModel.vertices);
game.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexInputLayout(myModel.inputLayout);

// Apply the basic effect technique and draw the object
basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
game.GraphicsDevice.Draw(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, myModel.vertices.ElementCount);
```

This is working fine for normal objects, however I would like to make some of the objects partially transparent. I've set the alpha value of these object's colors to 50, however they are still being rendered as opaque. What do I need to do to achieve this effect?

Comment: Depends on where you set the alpha value. Usually, this is a float in the range [0, 1].

Comment: OK thanks... I was setting the alpha value between [0, 100].

Comment: I'm running into a new problem though - whenever I set any of a new Color's variable to a decimal value it doesn't seem to set properly: I set it as 'public Color waterColor = new Color(0, 0, 205, 0.5f);' but when I print the color value is after assignment it says 'A:127 R:0 G:0 B:255'

Comment: That's why I asked about how you set the color. The `Color` has different constructors. Either use all `float` values in the range [0, 1] or all `byte` values in the range [0, 255]. You shouldn't mix it up.

Answer (score 0):

Transparency in Sharpdx requires alpha blending value 0..1 for float colors. The comment Nico Schertler provided above solved the question and can be regarded as answer.

Without Alpha mode, there are two options, that you can use in the HLSL shader file

- In the Pixel shader, use the clip() function, dependent on the input color. You could define your transparent black and *not show* any black triangles. Like so:

  `float4 PS( PS_IN input ) : SV_Target
  {
    clip(input.color[3] < 0.1f ? -1:1 );
    return input.color;
  }`

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-clip

See the effect:

[image]

- modify the Vertex Shader to project these vertices to (0,0,0), dependent on the input color. You could define your transparent black and *not show* any black triangles. Like so:

  `PS_IN VS( VS_IN input)
     {
      PS_IN output = (PS_IN)0;

      if ((input.color[0]!=0)||(input.color[1]!=0)||(input.color[2]!=0))
      {
        output.position = mul(worldViewProj,input.position);

      }
      output.color = input.color;
      return output;
     }`

See below the effect on the edges of my HeightField mesh, on the left is the unchanged version..

[image: https://i.ibb.co/GC7wwSp/Cheap-Transparent.jpg]

**NOTE**: The latter solution gives sharper edges, but it only works when (0,0,0) is behind the object.